# How to scrape only salient elements from HTML string

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm working on an iOS project, part of which allows the user to browse the web and save any web page locally to their device for reading at a later date.

I can do this by saving the HTML string or the contents in PDF format but ideally the saved content would be stripped of any unnecessary clutter, e.g. links, adverts, e.t.c. e.g. saving only the news story and nothing else from a news website.

I'm stuck on how to parse an HTML string and take only the relevant elements from it. If I was scraping from one website I could look specifically for certain elements and then compile a nice looking attributed string but I need to be able to scrape from anywhere.

I'm aware of Hpple and libxml2 which are brilliant for parsing HTML but I'm not sure of how to make the parsing generic enough for most websites.

My question is: if the above is possible how can I best go about achieving it?

Comment: If it is not your website and you have not been given explicit authorization and this is not only for your personal use it is a copyright infringement aka theft.

Comment: The app is only for personal use. I can copy and paste web pages to my heart's content on my Mac I'm sure that's not illegal. I'm not going to distribute website content just make it available offline. There are loads of apps for iOS and OS X that do similar things.

Comment: As I indicated, personal use is probably OK. OTOH I was doing that for comics just for me and I was banned from [User Friendly](http://www.userfriendly.org)--kind of oxymoronic given the name. :-; I contacted them and was told that they did not allow such usage.